# How to enter root shell, do commands, exit, and continue with script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I am currently writing a script which creates an Ubuntu img.
Since I want to customize such, I use `sudo chroot target bash script.sh` in my main script to change the root directory and automatically start script.sh written by me.

Now in the script, as a last command, I wrote `exit`. I want to exit this root directory and go back to the "normal" one and then want to continue with my script.
How is this possible?

If this is a little bit confusing, just ask and I will tell you more.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the question is not clear enough. What is asked is what it is done. When executing a simple command (not `exec` and without `&`), the shell process creates a new process and waits for its termination and special variable `$?` is updated with exit. All environment changes done by second process are lost when it exits and the caller shell environment is not changed, same as before calling the command.

If "my script" is the `script.sh` so the called process to exit from root directory and continue, it's not possible. Maybe an intermediate caller.sh could be created.

```
sudo bash caller.sh

# caller.sh
chroot target bash script.sh
# continue
```